# JAX-RS not responding at all (404)

Tags: eclipse, rest, jsp, tomcat, jax-rs

I'm using Eclipse 2020-03, Gradle and Tomcat. all I did follows.

1. Installing gradle through eclipse marketplace.
2. making gradle project.
3. adding those on build.gradle dependencies

```
    dependencies {
    // This dependency is exported to consumers, that is to say found on their compile classpath.
    api 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'

    // This dependency is used internally, and not exposed to consumers on their own compile classpath.
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:28.2-jre'

    // Use JUnit test framework
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    
    compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet:2.27'
    compile group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.inject', name: 'jersey-hk2', version: '2.27'
    compile group: 'javax.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-api', version: '2.4.0-b180830.0359'
    compile group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.media', name: 'jersey-media-json-jackson', version: '2.27'
}
```

4. adding "rest" package on src/main/java
5. adding ApplicationConfig.java and RestApiService.java on rest package.
6. ApplicationConfig.java

```
    package rest;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {
    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> getProperties(){
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        properties.put("jersey.config.server.provider.packages", "A_UnivG.rest");
        return properties;
    }
}
```

7. RestApiService.java

```
package rest;

import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import Data.*;

@Path("/Data")
public class RestApiService {
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("RestApiService");
    IntegrationDAO dao = new IntegrationDAO();
    
    @GET
    @Path("hello")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getHello() {return "Hello";}
    
}
```

and when I try to request http://localhost:portnumber/A_UnivG/api/Data/hello it spits out only 404 error.
cannot figure out why.

My project works with plain jsp files. I have a JSP page which uses DAO Read but it works just fine. well, that shouldn't be a problem I just tried hello world and it doesn't work at all.

Comment: How are you deploying and running this?

Comment: @nitind I'm kinda noob on web so can't 100% sure it's right description but I run it through eclipse 'run as' option and turns on tomcat.

Comment: "Run As" what? Does the Console view mention any ERRORs?

Comment: @nitind run as tomcat v9.0 server. and it mentions no errors. only 404 not found on browser. I hate it :(